# Apache POI works in linux without Microsoft office

Tags: java, linux, apache-poi

I have downloaded Apache POI in my linux machine, and I want to write java program which create excel file and store data in it.

My problem is, my machine don't have Microsoft office package.

Will Apache POI work in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes it will!

MS stuffs are not dependencies of POI lib. Otherwise, all applications with Poi supported must be deployed  to a Windows machine, what a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

`Apache POI` generates spreadsheets using `HSSFWorkbook` class and you can then save them as in `ODF` or `XLS` format.

```
File file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".XLS");

//Creating output stream to empty file
FileOutputStream fos =  new FileOutputStream(file);    

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

HSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");

HSSFRow row[] = new HSSFRow[size];

row[0] = createHeaderRow(firstSheet.createRow(0));

row[0].createCell(0).setCellValue("test value");

workbook.write(fos);
```